# Is there a way to find rows with NaN and then drop that as well as n number of rows after?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a spreadsheet where data is laid out in a strange way with chunks of data separated by a single empty row of NaN cells. I can remove the NaN rows with `drop.na` of course, however is there a way for me to drop those NaN rows as well as a specified number of rows beneath them?

For example I'd like to drop each of the NaN rows in the dataframe as well as the 2 rows below it that are not NaN.

Comment: You can obtain the rows with NaNs using `DataFrame().isna()` and work from there.

Comment: Thanks very much, would you be able to elaborate on this? How would I go from selecting the NaN rows with that to dropping the 2 rows below it?

Comment: What step do you not understand?

Comment: So I can obtain a list of rows with NaN using `DataFrame.isna()`, how do I then go from that list to automatically dropping all of the rows with NaN and 2 rows thereafter?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a mask from shifted column values, for example:

```py
# identify nan rows, true if nan
df['row_is_na'] = df['some_column'].isna()

# identify two rows that follow nan, true if after nan
df['rows_after_nan'] = df['row_is_na'].shift(-1) | df['row_is_na'].shift(-2)

# apply the mask
df = df[~df['rows_after_nan']]
```

Comment: Thanks very much I think this will work, only issue is I am looking at the entire dataframe for NaN rather than one column (where you have `df['some_column']isna()` I have tried just with `df.isna() ` but all rows return False when I do this

Comment: In that case, you want to do, `df.isna().sum(axis=1) == df.shape[1]` which will return the count of nans, and then compare it to the number of columns...